# antlr4 TSqlParser.g4/TSqlLexer.g4 case sensitivity issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, antlr4

I am using [These TSql Grammars/Lexers](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql) in order to parse stored procedures in a c# target.

I find that the following method has problems.

```
public override void EnterProcedure_param(Procedure_paramContext context)
{
    string txt = context.GetText();

    string datatype = context.data_type().GetText();

    if (IsUserDefinedType(datatype)) // not shown
        DoSomething(datatype);
}
```

It will correctly extract the datatype (and txt) when a stored procedure is defined :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_SomeProc]
    @APPINSTID BIGINT
AS ...
```

but NOT

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_SomeProc]
    @AppInstId BIGINT
AS ...
```

In the latter case txt is '@AI' and datatype is 'I'.

Further, if the parameter is defined `@appinstid`, the method never gets visited.

Does this mean the grammar has to be defective or am I perhaps missing something?

Comment: I suggest you open an issue on the [github project](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues). I've had good success parsing T-SQL with the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Transactsql.ScriptDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom?view=sql-dacfx-150) in C# and PowerShell, available in the [DacFx NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx/).

Comment: As the note on the main page clearly states: "As SQL grammar are normally not case sensitive but this grammar implementation is ..."

Comment: @SMor - so it does.  I missed that when i upgraded from an earlier non_cs grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CaseChangingCharStream` instead of standard token stream. See detail here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/case-insensitive-lexing.md

Comment: There is an error in the C# implementation of CaseChangingCharStream - Lines 71 & 73 'LA' should be 'La'.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not the error - it depends on C# runtimes: standard or optimized.